# Function notifies me that screen saver is turned on / windows

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, cmd, screensaver

Hi so my question is: is there any function or something like that, that will notify me that the screen saver is ON and the monitor is blanked.

If there are any question out there I'm sorry, I tried to read as much as i could

Comment: what message? if you will run two programs and one program will be send information to other program then it should work even if monitor is blanked.

Comment: I havent expressed myself correctly i mean if there is a function that will notify me (my programme) that the monitor is blanked i mean the computer is not touched for over (in my situation) 10 minutes and the screen saver is acivated, beacause i want to write a programme that will shut down my computer if it is 2 hours unused (dont know if it is even possible in python) ( and i know that there are many programms like that but i want to write to learn new things in python)

Comment: I want the monitor to be blanked before I iniciate clock because it will prevent my programme to shut down my computer while in my bed watching netflix 4 hours straight so and it will only turn off the device when its truly unused

Comment: @furas could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ there is a function called SystemParametersInfo that let you check is screensaver running or not.
So you can create exe in C++ that will check for screensaver and return result, and then you may execute it from python and check for result.

isScreensaverRunning.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
int main(){
    BOOL running;
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, &running, 0);
    return running;
}
```

isScreensaverRunning.py:

```
import os
isRunning= os.system("C:\\src\\isScreensaverRunning\\isScreensaverRunning.exe");
if( isRunning!=0 ):
   ...
```

You also mentioned that you just want to shutdown your computer 2 hours after starting screensaver. In Windows7 Power Saving Settings there is an option to put computer to Sleep or Hibernate after some time of inactivity.

Comment: Thank you sir. I know that I can just download or use a program that will do it  automatically, I just always wanted to do it on my own. Thank you a lot again.

Comment: You are welcome.
Power Saving Settings is not extra application. It's settings page in windows.

And SystemParametersInfo function is also build in to windows. You don't need C++ to call it. It's possible that you can call it from python, but I'm not 100% sure about that.